# Access invisible textinput element with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to access an input element, but VS throws me the following exception when I try to click or sendkeys into it:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'OpenQA.Selenium.ElementNotVisibleException' occurred in WebDriver.dll

Additional information: element not visible
```

After googling I found it that this is probably a invisible input element and I need to do it with a JavaScript Driver. I am not that good at C# and I have never worked with Selenium before, thus I fail to implement this part on my own, so I hope you can help me.

**This is what I see in the source code of the form when I inspect the element:**

```
<span class="origin-ux-textbox-control origin-ux-control">
<span>
<input id="ebi_email-input" maxlength="256" type="text" name="" value="peterparker@web.de" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off" autocomplete="off"></span>
</span>
```

**This is what I tried:**

```
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ebi_email-input")).Click();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ebi_email-input")).Clear();
driver.FindElement(By.Id("ebi_email-input")).SendKeys(email);
```

The exception is thrown at the first line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect some duplicate `ids` are being used. try to find how many elements are returned by `FindElements` method if more than one then I guess you can loop through and find the visible one and then send keys. Or, if you have to use javascript following should work as well.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) driver;
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("ebi_email-input"));
js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('value', 'youremailaddress')", element);
```